# How to retrieving image using PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, html

I'm trying to upload the student profile picture to mysql and then I want to retrieve those picture. now I can upload the image into mysql db successfully but, when I try to retrieve the image that doesn't retrieve properly. If anyone has an idea, please let me know. Thank you.
**Here is my code**

```html
<?php
echo' <form name="student" method="post" action="">  ';
echo' <div class="row">';
echo' <div class="col-md-4">';
echo '<label>Voter NIC no</label>';
echo'<input type="text" name="ty" class="form-control border-input" >';
echo'  </div></div>';
echo' <div class="col-md-4">
<div class="form-group">
<button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="se"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>  </div>    </div> </div> </form>';         
                                            
                                              
require'database.php'; 
$ty = isset($_POST['ty']) ? $_POST['ty'] : '';      
if(isset($_POST['se']))
 {
  $sql="SELECT `registr_no`, `frist_name`, `middle_name`, `last_name`,`NIC_number`,`voterPic_name`, `img_path`
FROM `voter`
  WHERE NIC_number='$ty'";
 $q1=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
echo'<form method="POST">';
echo"<table class='table table-striped'>";
echo"<thead>
          <th>Registr no</th>
             <th>First Name</th>
             <th>Middle Name</th>
             <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>NIC No </th>
     <th>Profile Pic</th>
     <th>Action</th>
   
              </thead> "; 
     
 while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($q1,MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
 $id=$rows['voter_registr_no'];
 $fname=$rows['frist_name'];
 $mname=$rows['middle_name'];
 $lname=$rows['last_name'];
 $pic =$rows['img_path'];
 $nic=$rows['NIC_number'];
 
  
echo"<tr><td>$id</td><td>$fname</td><td>$mname</td><td>$lname</td><td>$nic</td><td><img src='pictures/.$pic  alt=''  height='100' width='100''/> </td>
<td><button type='submit' name='ok' class='btn btn-sm btn-default'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-ok'></span></button></td></tr>";
echo"</table>

</form>";

}

}        

 ?>
```

As you can see the [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT3U3.jpg) here.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Image isn't retrieved in the output. See this link. Itz my output        https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT3U3.jpg

Comment: right click and paste url that you see in the src of the image

Comment: Actually, I want to get pictures from the database

Comment: If you want to get images from the database, what's 'img_path'?

Comment: try to open the image in a new tap, what is the link you get?

Comment: yes.I want to get images from the database. here is path C:\xampp\htdocs\student\pictures

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the link of the image is correct it should be something like that
**your-domain/pictures-folder-path/image-path/image-name-with-extension**

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you are storing only image name in DB and not the whole path. If you have stored full path in the database, then you need to only mention.

```
<img src='.$pic.  alt=''  height='100' width='100''/>
```

No need to add "pictures/" as you had already stored path in the database.